# Terraform Incompatible API version with plugin. Plugin version: 5, Core version: 4

Tags: plugins, terraform, grafana

Running into this module error no one on my team, which is all new, does not know. Below is my terraform version. And yes, I know terraform 0.11 is old as hell but I was just hired and have to fix this.

$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.14

- provider.aws v2.70.0
- provider.grafana v1.10.0
- provider.kubernetes v1.8.0
- provider.null v2.1.2
- provider.postgresql v1.7.2
- provider.random v2.3.1

Error:

Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error occurred:
* module.editedout-dev-keycloak.provider.grafana: Incompatible API version with plugin. Plugin version: 5, Core version: 4

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that you have a number of questions with answeres, yet not a single one was accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice but it limits number of duplicates. @MattSchuchard answer is good, as you even claim in the comments "that worked like a charm". So why not accept it and help others?

Comment: Thanks for that as well. Haven't been on in a while and missed that.

Comment: No problem. Glad the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [documented requirements](https://github.com/grafana/terraform-provider-grafana/tree/v1.10.0#requirements) for the Grafana provider version 1.10, the minimum core version of Terraform for that version of the provider is 0.12. The reason for this can be seen referenced in the CHANGELOG with [issue 159](https://github.com/grafana/terraform-provider-grafana/issues/159). The provider upgraded to version 2 of the provider SDK, which enforces core Terraform at minimum version 0.12. More details around that minimum version bump can be read in that issue description.

If you want to move forward, then you would need to lock in the Grafana provider to version 1.9.0. In Terraform version 0.11, you would achieve that with the following declarative syntax in a config file for the root module config, or preferably in the module declared as `editedout-dev-keycloak` in the error message you displayed:

```
provider "grafana" {
  version = "1.9.0"
}
```